# How do I get jQuery to change classes according to an If/Then statement. My 'home' link will not change class when another link clicked on

Tags: jquery, css, function, hyperlink, click

How do I get my jQuery code to state the following:

IF 'home page' active, THEN 'home link' 'CSS class: A' (color:dark green); ELSE 'home link' 'CSS class: B' (color:brown).

*(Ultimately: to indicate what page I am on, I want the relevant link to be 'dark green' with no hover effect; and for those links which are not active, I want them to be brown and I want them to turn light green when hovered on.)*

At the moment, the code I have works exactly as I want it to except for one thing - when I click on any link the dark green does not disappear from the 'home' link. This is because of the CSS: #menuDisplayedHome a { color: #568a38; /* Dark Green * } .... See: https://jsfiddle.net/mhfn7kw0/2/embedded/result/ (Press 'about' followed by 'home' to see slider).

**N.b. all the pages are on a jQuery slider, so all 'pages' are actually on the same page (as far as I know).**

Current code:

CSS:

```
#menuDisplayed a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #8F5C3E;    /* Brown */
        }

    #menuDisplayed a:not(.no-hover):hover { /* only apply hover styling when the div does not have the class 'no-hover' */
        color:#6bab4a ;   /* Light Green */
        }

    #menuDisplayedHome a  {
        color: #568a38; /* Dark Green */
        }   

    #menuDisplayed a.no-hover {
        color: #568a38;       /* Dark Green */
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="headingLogoBar">
        <div id="logoBarImageDiv">
            <img id=""/>
        </div>

        <div id="menuDisplayed">
                <ul>
                    <li id="menuDisplayedHome"><a href="#target1" class="forMovingPanel">HOME</li>
                    <li id="menuDisplayedAbout"><a href="#target2" class="forMovingPanel">ABOUT</a></li>        
                    <li id="menuDisplayedPortfolio"><a href="#target3" class="forMovingPanel">PORTFOLIO</a></li>    
                    <li id="menuDisplayedContact"><a href="#target4" class="forMovingPanel">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="forMovingPanel active" id="target1" style="left:0; display:block;">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Home</h3>
    </div>


    <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target2">
            <h3 style="text-align:center">About</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target3" >
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Portfolio</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="forMovingPanel" id="target4" >
        <h3 style="text-align:center">Contact</h3>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery for changing link colors:

```
<script>

$('#menuDisplayedHome a').on('click', function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    });

$('#menuDisplayedAbout a').on('click', function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover');
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').addClass('menuDisplayed a');
    });

$('#menuDisplayedContact a').on('click', function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').addClass('menuDisplayed a');
    });

$('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').on('click', function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').addClass('menuDisplayed a');
    });

</script>
```

jQuery for slider:

```
        jQuery(function($) {

$('a.forMovingPanel').click(function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if ($(".forMovingPanel").is(':animated')) return false;

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });

        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});

});
```

Comment: What is this `.addClass('menuDisplayed a')` meant to accomplish? Without it, you could reduce this wall of four click handlers to one delegated click handler: `$("#menuDisplayed").on("click", "a", function() { var link = $(this); link.closest("ul").find(".no-hover").removeClass("no-hover"); link.addClass("no-hover"); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say first, I would use the `.click()` property in stead of `.on()`. To my understanding, you have to start `.on()` with `$(document)` also, in stead of the thing to be clicked on. Then put that thing within the parameters.

Also, you're trying to addClass = "menuDisplayed a". That is not a class: `menuDisplayed` was an ID that you had called. I would change some of my IDs into classes and tidy it up a little if I were you; keep in mind that IDs are more specific than classes.

In my opinion, it's better to start all of your `<a>` tags in the same class (or without the `no-hover` class). Then when the `$(document)` is `.ready()`, you can tell jQuery to automatically load HOME to dark-green without a click or other event. Just when the page finishes loading.
I would rewrite the jQuery for classes like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menuDisplayedHome a').addClass('no-hover');

$('#menuDisplayedHome a').click(function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    });

$('#menuDisplayedAbout a').click(function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover');
    });

$('#menuDisplayedContact a').click(function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    });

$('#menuDisplayedPortfolio a').click(function() {      /* when you click the div */
    $(this).addClass('no-hover');     /* add the class 'no-hover' = dark green */
    $('#menuDisplayedAbout a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedContact a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    $('#menuDisplayedHome a').removeClass('no-hover'); 
    });
});
```

and my resulting CSS:

```
.menuDisplayed a {
        text-decoration:none;
        color: #8F5C3E;    /* Brown */
        }

.menuDisplayed a:not(.no-hover):hover { /* only apply hover styling when the div does not have the class 'no-hover' */
        color:#6bab4a ;   /* Light Green */
        }

    .menuDisplayed a.no-hover  {
        color: #568a38; /* Dark Green */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be the simplest. Add the `no-hover` class to the home link.